# Can I improve my bitmap processing?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm downloading a bitmap. Copy it into a mutable bitmap and replace all the Magenta pixels for transparent pixels. Especially the copy part seems like a waste of resources to me. How can I improve this?

```
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;

    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Bitmap copy = mIcon11.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    mIcon11.recycle();
    int [] allpixels = new int [ copy.getHeight()*copy.getWidth()];
    copy.getPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());
    for(int i =0; i < copy.getHeight() * copy.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        if( allpixels[i] == Color.MAGENTA)
        {
            allpixels[i] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        }
    }
    copy.setPixels(allpixels, 0, copy.getWidth(), 0, 0, copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight());
```

Comment: Out of the topic but is this a Red eye removal?

Comment: Have you looked at RenderScript? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like:

```
Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIcon11.getWidth(), mIcon11.getHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

for(int x = 0; x < mIcon11.getWidth(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < mIcon11.getHeight(); y++){
        if(mIcon11.getPixel(x, y) != Color.MAGENTA){
            finalBitmap.setPixel(x, y, mIcon11.getPixel(x, y)); 
        }else{
            finalBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

I Just Did This Off The Top Of My Head, It Should Work. If This Doesn't Work, Try Using Hex Values Instead Of Colors(Ex: Color.MAGENTA; 0xff00ff) That Can Be Used If Your Magenta Is Not The Same As Color.MAGENTA, Or Any Color You Want. Most Image Editing Programs Show The Hex Value Of Your Color.

Comment: Why would this be better?